# Is $x \mapsto \mu( \text{supp}f_x)$ continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions, borel-measures

Let $X$ be a measurable space equipped with a complex Borel measure $\mu$, and let $\{f_x\}_{x\in X}$ be a family of continuous functions $f_x:X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that the function $X\rightarrow \mathbb{C} (x\mapsto f_x(y))$ is continuous for all $y\in X$. We set
$$\text{supp}f_x=\{y\in X: f_x(y)\neq 0\}.$$
Then is the function $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}(x\mapsto \mu(\text{supp}f_x))$ integrable? If not, what is an assumption for the space $X$ (or the measure $\mu$) for which it holds? Furthermore, is the function $F$ continuous?

Comment: The function $F$ surely isn't continuous is general right? For example, take $X = \mathbb C$ with the standard measure and $f_x(y) = x$ (the constant function whose value is $x$). Then the support is $\mathbb C$ for all $x \neq 0$ and is the empty set for $x = 0$, so $F(0) = 0$ but $F(x) = \infty$ for all other $x$ so $F$ is not continuous, right?

Comment: As an aside, what is the source/motivation for this problem?

Comment: also note the example above shows $F$ is horribly far from being integrable to a finite value in any reasonable sense, being infinity a.e. An obvious (though perhaps too strong) condition would be to require compact supports

Comment: Sure, it is true. The motivation is Peter-Weyl Theorem (page49 in https://math.tkk.fi/opetus/harmanal/pruju/group08.pdf). In this lecture, we consider the integration $$\int_G \mu_G(M(x)) \mu_G(x),$$ but it is not obvious that $x\mapsto \mu_G(M(x))$ is integrable, where $G$ is a compact group, where $\mu_G$ is the Haar measure, and where $M(x)$ is a support for a continuous function appearing in the proof.

Comment: of critical importance there is that $G$ is compact, so that $\mu_G$ is finite, which helps force the integral to be finite (and it's well defined since $\mu_g \circ M$ will be Borel). To prove finiteness, simply look at the equation: it's equal to $\mu_{G \times G}(K)$, essentially by definition, and this latter measure must be finite ($G \times G$ must be compact since $G$ is so $\mu_{G \times G}$ finite). In fact, the calculation shows it to be zero. In the general case you provided, having $X$ be a compact group is essentially a strengthened version of the condition I gave (compact supps)

Comment: I'd have to check the details carefully, but it seems to me that integrability should generically follow from essentially the same argument as in the notes you linked whenever the measure is finite on the sets we are concerned with (which appropriate compactness of the supports should give, though one could surely get weaker if we knew something more about the measure). In the case of a generic non-finite measure without compactness requirements, I would guess an example akin to but generalizing the one I gave above would cause failure in some cases.

Comment: In the compact group case, is that you say $$\int_G \mu_G(M(x)) d\mu_G(x)=\mu_{G\times G}(K)< \infty,$$ by the definition? I agree with $\mu_{G\times G}(K)< \infty$, but I think that the first equation follows from the Fubini Theorem as $$\int_G \mu_G(M(x)) d\mu_G(x)=\int_G \int_G 1_{M(x)}(y) d\mu_G(y) d\mu_G(x) =\int_{G\times G} 1_{M(x)}(y) d\mu_{G\times G}(x,y) =\int_{G\times G} 1_K d\mu_{G\times G}= \mu_{G\times G}(K),$$  if the function $x\mapsto \mu_G(M(x))$ is integrable. Is it not correct, or induced by the definition immediately without Fubini Theorem?

Comment: At least in the $\sigma$-finite case we have, for every measurable set $E$, that: $(\mu_1 \times \mu_2)(E) = \int_{X_1} \mu_2(E_x) d\mu_1(x)$. In this case $\mu_{G \times G}(K) = \int_{X_1} \mu_G(K_x) d\mu_G(x)$ where $K_x := \{y \in G \mid (x,y) \in K\}=:M(x)$. The proof I have accessible via Folland follows directly from Carathéodory's Extension Theorem and does not seem to assume anything other than that $E$ (or in this case, $K$) is measurable. You are correct that I'm not quite sure what to do outside the $\sigma$-finite case, since I almost exclusively encounter such measures

Comment: Is Folland's book you said http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/f2017/Folland_A_Guide.pdf ?

Comment: No, his real analysis text (it's one of the most common sources on the topic). It's Theorem 2.36 (page 66 on my copy) of the second edition.

Comment: As an aside, I found the following comment from the user Aweygan) where LCG = Locally Compact Group): *"Indeed, not every LCG is σ-finite with respect to Haar measure (consider any uncountable group with the discrete topology). However Fubini's theorem still works most of the time, since most functions dealt with vanish outside some σ-compact set. Section 2.2 of Folland's A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis deals exactly with the concerns you have, so I would recommend reading that."*. It would seem that in many cases local compactness will suffice, though I haven't read that text myself.

Comment: Ofc, if we have compactness rather than just local compactness, we get global finiteness and thus $\sigma$-finiteness for free so the claim in the paper holds. I would be intruiged to see if we could consider locally compact supports though that vanish outside some $\sigma$-compact set... You might be able to glue them together to get a fairly general criterion for the claim in your post to hold.

Comment: It is interested, I think. I learned a lot from your comments. Thank you.